How to add oss-license plugin to Android App
How can I add the oss Licenser from Google to my Android app?
I have already implemented implementation(libs.play.services.oss.licences). However, every time I open the activity, the following error message appears

This App does not have any open source licences

This makes no sense at all, as my app definitely contains open source licenses. Do you know why this could be? As far as I have understood the instructions correctly, a plugin has to be added.
How exactly do I do this in the new build.gradle.kts? Link to Github: https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/main/oss-licenses-plugin
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

    dependencies {
    
        implementation(libs.appcompat)
        implementation(libs.material)
        implementation(libs.activity)
        implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
        implementation(libs.preference)
        testImplementation(libs.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    
    
        implementation(libs.play.services.oss.licenses)
        implementation (libs.lottie)
    }



I was able to solve the question on my own now. Thanks for your comment anyway :)

I have just solved the problem by adding the following code in build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    ...

}
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.oss.licenses.plugin)
    }
}

